# RSpec routes recognision

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have an interesting situation which leaves me scratching my head.
I've created a controller (without a model) to generate password resets.  I've defined a RESTful route to the controller:

**routes.rb**

```
resources :password_resets
```

I've created some action on the controller, in particular my edit action:

**password_resets_controller.rb**

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  # code omitted
  def edit
    @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
  end
  # code omitted
end
```

The user can access the edit from the email that I send to the user:

**password_reset.html.haml**

```
%p To reset your password, click the URL below.
= edit_password_reset_url(@user.password_reset_token)
```

So far so good, I've managed to use the code.
Then I have the spec that tests my mailer:

```
  describe "password reset" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let(:mail) { UserMailer.password_reset(user) }

    it "sends user password reset url" do
      mail.to.should eq([user.email])
    end
  end
```

Surprisingly, I get the following:

```
 Failure/Error: let(:mail) { UserMailer.password_reset(user) }
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"password_resets"}
 # ./app/views/user_mailer/password_reset.html.haml:5:in `_app_views_user_mailer_password_reset_html_haml__1760284087840822602_11954840'
 # ./app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:7:in `password_reset'
```

Yet there is a route match, at least by looking at my routes:

```
 password_resets GET    /password_resets(.:format)             password_resets#index
                       POST   /password_resets(.:format)             password_resets#create
    new_password_reset GET    /password_resets/new(.:format)         password_resets#new
   edit_password_reset GET    /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)    password_resets#edit
        password_reset GET    /password_resets/:id(.:format)         password_resets#show
                       PUT    /password_resets/:id(.:format)         password_resets#update
                       DELETE /password_resets/:id(.:format)         password_resets#destroy
```

What could possible go wrong in my test/routes?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if Factory `user` has `password_reset_token`. Most likely it is nil, same routing error you can get for any `edit_something_url(nil)`

Comment: That was indeed what was happening!  A bit confusing error message from RSpec, but hey, now I will know.  Thank you very much!